# Unterminated string constant during @Html.Partial from javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

```
var html = '@Html.Partial("_mypartialview")';
$("#container").html(html);
```

I am working in a single page application and I don't want to hide the container div element; instead I want to load the html content into my javascript object.

But I get the error:

> Unterminated string constant.

I have tried various methods without any success. Any help as to why I get this error would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is that all your code? Check which line the error is thrown on, because no error is thrown for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
var html = "@Html.Partial("_mypartialview").ToHtmlString().Replace("\n", "<br/>").Replace(" ", "")";
```

The ToHtmlString() method HTML encodes your html so the quotes won't confuse your JavaScript.

The two replace methods will remove new lines and whitespace so the content is all on one line.

**Update**

_mypartialview

```
 <div>
     <span data-bind="text:playerInfo.Name"> </span> 
</div>
```

Code

```
 var html = "@Html.Partial("_mypartialview").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace(" ", "")"
```

This outputs the following

```
var html = "&lt;div&gt;&lt;spandata-bind=&quot;text:playerInfo.Name&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/div&gt;"
```

Comment: Thanks. But still i get the same error. And the content is not in single line.

Comment: Strange it works fine for me. Can you give me the html for your partial view and I will try and reproduce the issue?

Comment: Nothing much really <div>
    Hello
</div>

Comment: I am using asp.net mvc 5 and i copied ur code ditto.

Comment: OK I've made an update based on your html. I needed to remove the new lines.