# Html.Partial in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I'm trying to render a partial view within my javascript code. The partial view itself contains JS codes as well, it's a kendo window.

This is my code, with changes suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28761693/unterminated-string-constant-during-html-partial-from-javascript-object):

```
var win = "@Html.Partial("_GenericWindow").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace(" ", "")";

$(".body-content").append(win);
```

But this code renders string in my page:

`<divid="7067ea1a-0425-44a6-99d3-aefb37f088ed"></div><script> jQuery(function(){jQuery("#7067ea1a-0425-44a6-99d3-aefb37f088ed").kendoWindow({"modal":false,"iframe":false,"draggable":true,"scrollable":true,"pinned":false,"title":null,"resizable":true,"content":null,"actions":["Close","Minimize","Refresh"]});});</script>`

And finally, this is my partial view:

```
@{
    var winId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}

@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name(winId)
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
    .Actions(actions => actions.Close().Minimize().Refresh())
)
```

Comment: replace ToString() to ToHtmlString().

Comment: I've tried that before, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this line works fine:

```
$('.body-content').load('/Home/win?window='.concat(text));
```

And the `win` action will return the partial view.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is MVC is preventing you from injecting raw HTML to the response stream.

You can modify your code by introducing @Html.Raw() to tell MVC that you want it to inject the raw HTML

ex..

```
var win = "@Html.Raw(@Html.Partial("_GenericWindow").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace(" ", ""))";

$(".body-content").append(win);
```

Comment: Thanks Chintana, now I get the `Expected ';'` error. This is win: `var win = "<div id="f7be8297-92a2-4aef-936b-4b531de497b4"></div><script> jQuery(function(){jQuery("#f7be8297-92a2-4aef-936b-4b531de497b4").kendoWindow({"modal":false,"iframe":false,"draggable":true,"scrollable":true,"pinned":false,"title":null,"resizable":true,"content":null,"actions":["Close","Minimize","Refresh"]});});</script>";`

Comment: This is my current line: `var win = "@Html.Raw(@Html.Partial("_GenericWindow").ToHtmlString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""))";` Also, I'll be thankful if you could guide me about getting the window's handle too.

Comment: This might be due to something going wrong at the server side code. You can test this by replacing all code in  _GenericWindow with a simple html message and see whether renders

Comment: The problem is I'll have JS code inside the returned value. I just want to have [multiple windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817307/opening-multiple-windows-with-kendo-menu/29837117#29837117), any better way?

Comment: In that case, you will have to use ajax to call the partial view

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570127/render-partial-view-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Yes, I can have simple HTML. JS code is causing the issue.